# Route with query params

Tags: flutter

I'm implementing the password recover in my web app.

After filling out the form, I receive in my email the link that should lead to the page in which i can change my password.

The link is something like: `.../new-password?token=[...]&code=[...]`

In my routing i have `/new-password` (with the corresponding screen) but if I click in the link I got the message error Routing doesn't exsist.

I guess I have to change the route but I don't understand how.

I'm using `onGenerateRoute`to keep track of all routes.